# Selenium WebDriver C# N Unit Reporting

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am new to N Unit and Visual Studio 2015. Where do I find the N Unit Reporting such as the xml output? I have added NUnit successfully into my visual studio project but am not sure what to do once I have ran a test. In previous experience using Java and Eclipse I used TestNG/ReportNG after the test ran I was able to succesfully pull my results from an html file and view the results in a browser. Is there something comparable to this?

Comment: There are many ways to run NUnit tests and you haven't said how you are doing it: console runner, gui, test explorer, r#, etc. Also, please tell us what version of each you are using.

Comment: I am using NUnitTestAdaptor.WithFramework Version 2.0.0     I am using Text Explorer to Run the Tests. Please let me know if anything elease is needed @Charlie

Comment: That's sufficient. Unfortunately, it leads to the answer that the NUnit VS adapter does not write the XML results to a file. The reason it doesn't have that feature is that it's an adapter: that is, it's goal is to make NUnit tests look like the kind of tests that Visual Studio understands. Of course, the XML is there, so it would be possible to write it. Somebody would need to file an issue asking for it.